# Shiny reactive works only if print the input variables

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am creating Joyplot in one of my shiny app. It allows users to make choices of  fill colors using `radioGroupButtons`. What I do here is, first I generate the plot through `reactive` and then use reactive output inside the `renderPlot`. See the minimal code given below. The problem is, code inside `reactive` only executes if I print input variable `print(input$joy_plot_fill)` **(the first line inside the reactive)**. Otherwise not. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(ggridges)
shinyApp(
  ui = 
    fluidPage(
      shinyWidgets::radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "joy_plot_fill",
        label = "Fill choices", individual = T,
        choices = c("A" = "A", "B" = "B", "C" = "C", "D" = "D", "E" = "E"),
        selected = "C"
      ),

      plotOutput(outputId = "joyplot")
    ),

  server =
    function(input, output, session) {

      plot_data <- reactive({
        plot_data <- mtcars  %>% as_tibble() %>% dplyr::select(mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat)
        plot_data_l <- plot_data %>% tidyr::gather(variable, value)
        return(plot_data_l) 

      })

      jp <- reactive({
        #print(input$joy_plot_fill)
        ggjoy_plot <- ggplot(plot_data()) +
          ggridges::stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient" , 
                              mapping = aes(x = value, y = variable, fill = ..quantile..), 
                              calc_ecdf = TRUE , quantiles = 4, quantile_lines = T) +
          viridis::scale_fill_viridis(name = "Prob" , option = input$joy_plot_fill, discrete = T)
        return(ggjoy_plot)
      })

      output$joyplot <- renderPlot({
        jp()
      })

    }
)
```

**=====UPDATES==========**

Changing fill inside `ggridges::stat_density_ridges` from `..quantile..` to `0.5 - abs(0.5 - ..ecdf..)` which fill color by probability instead of quantile works even without `print` line in the `reactive`. See the code below. I do not understand how reactive block get alert in the the second scenario but not in the first.

```
    library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(ggridges)
shinyApp(
  ui = 
    fluidPage(
      shinyWidgets::radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "joy_plot_fill",
        label = "Fill choices", individual = T,
        choices = c("A" = "A", "B" = "B", "C" = "C", "D" = "D", "E" = "E"),
        selected = "C"
      ),

      actionButton("plot" , label = "Plot"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "joyplot")
    ),

  server =
    function(input, output, session) {

      plot_data <- reactive({
        plot_data <- mtcars  %>% as_tibble() %>% dplyr::select(mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat)
        plot_data_l <- plot_data %>% tidyr::gather(variable, value)
        return(plot_data_l) 

      })

      jp <- reactive({
        #print(input$joy_plot_fill)
        ggjoy_plot <- ggplot(plot_data()) +
          ggridges::stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient" , 
                              mapping = aes(x = value, y = variable,  fill = 0.5 - abs(0.5 - ..ecdf..)), 
                              calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
          viridis::scale_fill_viridis(name = "quantile" , option = input$joy_plot_fill, discrete = F)
        return(ggjoy_plot)
      })

      output$joyplot <- renderPlot({
        jp()
      })

    } 
)
```

Comment: in your update things have changed now. The `jp` function doesn't exist and this should pretty much work even if you go back to your `quantile` implementation. Notice that you are executing the `ggplot` directly inside `renderPlot` and not inside a reactive block as was the case with `jp()` previously

Comment: I'm sorry.! I added version with `jp()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
shinyApp(
  ui = 
    fluidPage(
      shinyWidgets::radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "joy_plot_fill",
        label = "Fill choices", individual = T,
        choices = c("A" = "A", "B" = "B", "C" = "C", "D" = "D", "E" = "E"),
        selected = "C"
      ),

      plotOutput(outputId = "joyplot")
    ),

  server =
    function(input, output, session) {

      plot_data <- reactive({
        plot_data <- mtcars  %>% as_tibble() %>% dplyr::select(mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat)
        plot_data_l <- plot_data %>% tidyr::gather(variable, value)
        return(plot_data_l) 

      })

      output$joyplot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(plot_data()) +
          ggridges::stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient" , 
                                        mapping = aes(x = value, y = variable, fill = ..quantile..), 
                                        calc_ecdf = TRUE , quantiles = 4, quantile_lines = T) +
          viridis::scale_fill_viridis(name = "quantile" , option = input$joy_plot_fill, discrete = T)
      })

    }
)
```

**Explanation**

Let's make the concept of `reactive` simple.

> In Shiny, there are three kinds of objects in reactive programming:
>   reactive sources, reactive conductors, and reactive endpoints

The source is user input (`input$joy_plot_fill` in your case). A reactive endpoint is usually something that appears in the user’s browser window, such as `output$joyplot` in your case.

So when you use `renderPlot` for `output$joyplot` and passing `input$joy_plot_fill` as  parameter, you are inherently making sure that it makes smart optimized choices when it tries to render the plot.

Nice move with making `plot_data` reactive, now *that* is called a reactive conductor, but it only matter matters in case the data is large and you don’t want to run it more times than is absolutely necessary.

**Update**

For the `print` problem, I will try and explain.

The `reactive` function by nature is trying to execute as less as possible. If some input changes, the reactive block is triggered if it detects a dependency on that input.

In your case when you are passing `input$joy_plot_fill` as a parameter to a `ggplot` function, the reactive block is unable to reach that code and detect the change (since it is an argument inside a function).

This is not a specific print problem. Try changing the print line to `abcd <- input$joy_plot_fill` - again, this does nothing, but somehow this brings reactive's attention to this input component so it executes again.

Try setting a breakpoint before the `jp` function and debug this line by line you will know what I am talking about.

**Update 2**

I did get what you are trying to say, but unfortunately its near impossible to explain.

Here what will *definitely* work for you.

1. Before starting your shiny app, set `options(shiny.reactlog=TRUE)`
2. In the case that works (`ecdf`), start the shiny app, click `A`, and then press `Ctrl+F3`. This brings out the reactor execution lineage graph. Here you will see that somehow it needs to recalculate/re-evaluate the expression `0.5 - abs(0.5 - ..ecdf..)` and so the plot renders because there is now a direct dependency (I know it sounds vague but once you see the execution graph you will know what I am talking about)
3. In the case that does not work (`quantile`), you will notice that it somehow doesn't need to execute the ggplot statement as it has all objects cached in and doesn't need to recompute `quantile`. (Again, you will know once you see the graph)

Hope that helps! Merry Christmas!!!

Comment: Agree to your explanation. Can you tell me code version of mine only works while using print statement and not otherwise ???

Comment: Hi Vivek, +1 for your clear explanation. My understanding was if any input changes, reactive will be executed if it depends on  input changed. However, as you said in my case input is an argument inside the function, the reactive block is unable to reach that code that is something new to me. I have one more counter argument to your answer. Updating in the question. Thanks.!

Comment: I post an update in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thanks a lot. I got the point what you explained. Wish you also merry Christmas  !! Cheers.